# Undefined symbols for architecture armv7 flutter

Tags: ios, flutter

When i build for generic devices or run for real devices it gives me following error on xcode

```
ld: warning: Could not find auto-linked framework 'Flutter' Undefined symbols for architecture armv7:   "_FlutterMethodNotImplemented", referenced from:
      -[FLTDeviceInfoPlugin handleMethodCall:result:] in DeviceInfoPlugin.o   "_OBJC_CLASS_$_FlutterMethodChannel", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in DeviceInfoPlugin.o ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture armv7 clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

And flutter build command runs without error

flutter doctor:

```
121:flutter_module sumeetjain$ flutter doctor Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v): [✓] Flutter (Channel stable, v1.9.1+hotfix.2, on Mac OS X 10.14.6 18G95, locale en-IN) [✗] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices
    ✗ Unable to locate Android SDK.
      Install Android Studio from: https://developer.android.com/studio/index.html
      On first launch it will assist you in installing the Android SDK components.
      (or visit https://flutter.dev/setup/#android-setup for detailed instructions).
      If the Android SDK has been installed to a custom location, set ANDROID_HOME to that location.
      You may also want to add it to your PATH environment variable.

[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS (Xcode 10.3) [!] Android Studio (not installed) [✓] Connected device (2 available)

! Doctor found issues in 2 categories.
```

But when i changed channel to master, error doesn't come.
Since i want to release my app, i cant do that on Master channel right !

Master channel flutter doctor

```
[✓] Flutter (Channel master, v1.10.3-pre.70, on Mac OS X 10.14.6 18G95, locale en-IN)
[✗] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices
    ✗ Unable to locate Android SDK.
      Install Android Studio from: https://developer.android.com/studio/index.html
      On first launch it will assist you in installing the Android SDK components.
      (or visit https://flutter.dev/setup/#android-setup for detailed instructions).
      If the Android SDK has been installed to a custom location, set ANDROID_HOME to that location.
      You may also want to add it to your PATH environment variable.

[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS (Xcode 10.3)
[!] Android Studio (not installed)
[!] Connected device
    ! No devices available

! Doctor found issues in 3 categories.
```

Answer (score 0):

This was a bug on Flutter's side. The only fix to this issue was to upgrade the SDK version that you're using. The [issue doesn't occur on master](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/40683#issuecomment-533243071) and the fix should be rolled out to stable as well.